Export data from local excel file to Google sheets
I have some local excel files that are connected to cubes and I'm trying to search a way that I could export this data from the local excel file to my google sheets using the google sheets ID.
I've been searching for something but I couldn't find out.
For excel, I have the version "microsoft 365 apps for business version 2405"
I found this link but the environment of the VBA looks quite different on my excel
https://vbaexpertonline.blogspot.com/2023/07/excel-vba-to-send-data-from-excel-sheet.html

May be not possible.
